# Deleting widgets (involving tkinter module)

Tags: python, tkinter

new guy here and I'm slowly getting the hang of python, but I have a question.

I have two files here

one is named first_file.py

```
from other_file import GameFrame
from Tkinter import Tk

def main():
    tk = Tk()
    tk.title("Game of Life Simulator")
    tk.geometry("380x580")
    GameFrame(tk)
    tk.mainloop()
main()
```

and the other is other_file.py

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *

class GameFrame (Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self,root)
        self.grid()
        self.mychosenattribute=8 
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        for rows in range(1,21):
            for columns in range(1,21):
                self.columns = columns
                self.rows = rows
                self.cell = Button(self, text='X')
                self.cell.bind("<Button-1>", self.toggle)
                self.cell.grid(row=self.rows, column=self.columns)

    reset = Button(self, text="Reset")
    reset.bind("<Button-1>", self.reset_button)
    reset.grid(row=22, column = 3, columnspan=5)

    def reset_button(self, event):
        self.cell.destroy()
        for rows in range(1,21):
               for columns in range(1,21):
                   self.columns = columns
                   self.rows = rows
                   self.cell = Button(self, text='')
                   self.cell.bind("<Button-1>", self.toggle)
                   self.cell.grid(row=self.rows, column=self.columns)
```

After I push the reset button what happens right now is one button gets destroyed and another set of buttons are made on top of the already present buttons, but I need to be able to destroy or atleast configure all buttons to be blank. So how would I do that for all the buttons since I used a for loop to generate them? (Is there a better way to generate the buttons besides using a for loop?) Thanks.

Comment: What is that `self.x`? Is it your frame or what?

Comment: oops.. that should be self.cell.. I'll go ahead and change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common method is to save your objects in a list (or dictionary) in order to access them when needed. A simple example:

```
self.mybuttons = defaultdict(list)
for rows in range(1,21):
    for columns in range(1,21):
        self.mybuttons[rows].append(Button(self, text=''))
```

Then you can get buttons, this way:

```
abutton = self.mybuttons[arow][acolumn]
```

There are some problems with your code that prevent running  it (indentation of the `reset` lines and the use of the undefined `self.toggle`), so I could not fix it, but this example should be enough for you to do it.