# Finding widgets on a grid (tkinter)

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

Using the `tkinter` module, suppose I create a grid with 50 button widgets and each of those widgets has different text. I need to be able to specify some way of typing in a row and column so I can get that widget's text at that location.

For example, if I need the widget's text at the third row in the second column of the grid. I've searched the docs but that tells me how to get info about widgets, when I need info about the grid.

Comment: Pls clarify, it is difficult to understand what are you asking for. You say that each button widget has a text and that you want that text, and later you say you want info about the grid not about the button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269824/deleting-widgets-involving-tkinter-module/8274479#8274479) relative to a method to save button objects in a dictionary in order to recover them using their (column, row) position in a grid.

So if self.mybuttons is your dictionary of lists of buttons as described in previous answer, then you can get the text at position row, col as this:

```
abutton = self.mybuttons[arow][acolumn]
text_at_row_col = abutton["text"]
```

On the other hand, if what you need is to get the text from the button callback:

```
button.bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)
```

then you can get the button text from the event, you do not need to know its row/col position, only to press it:

```
def callback(self, event):
    mybutton = event.widget
    text_at_row_col = mybutton["text"]
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no need to create your own function or keep a list/dictionary, tkinter already has a built-in [`grid_slaves()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_slaves-method) method.
It can be used as `frame.grid_slaves(row=some_row, column=some_column)`

Here's an example with a grid of buttons showing how `grid_slaves()` retrieves the widget, as well as displaying the text.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

# Show grid_slaves() in action
def printOnClick(r, c):
    widget = root.grid_slaves(row=r, column=c)[0]
    print(widget, widget['text'])

# Make some array of buttons
for r in range(5):
    for c in range(5):
        btn = tk.Button(root, text='{} {}'.format(r, c),
                        command=lambda r=r, c=c: printOnClick(r, c))
        btn.grid(row=r, column=c)

tk.mainloop()
```