# python tkinter how to change the label of a widget on a particular grid space?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, grid

I have a 3x3 grid of buttons, all of which are bound to the same event funciton. This function changes the labels of particular buttons, based on which button was clicked. I want to be able to choose which buttons will be effected by looking at where they fall on the grid, i.e. row and column values.

For example, I want to be able to say "considering the button clicked was on (row 1, column 2), I want to change the labels of the buttons on (row 2, column 0) and (row 1, column 1).

I know how to find the row and column of the button which was clicked:

```
import tkinter

def click(event):
    space = event.widget
    space_label = space['text']
    row = space.grid_info()['row'] #get the row of clicked button
    column = space.grid_info()['column'] #get the column of clicked button

board = tkinter.Tk()

for i in range(0,9): #creates the 3x3 grid of buttons

    button = tkinter.Button(text = "0")

    if i in range(0,3):
        r = 0
    elif i in range(3,6):
        r = 1
    else:
        r = 2

    button.grid(row = r, column = i%3)
    button.bind("<Button-1>",click)

board.mainloop()
```

But I can't figure out how to access a button's label given only a row and column of the grid.

P.S. new to coding, sorry if this is obvious, i looked around but couldn't find any similar enough questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding widgets on a grid (tkinter module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369560/finding-widgets-on-a-grid-tkinter-module)

Comment: I'm new to programming so I don't know much about the lambda function or grid slaves, but this does in theory seem to answer the quesiton, so thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to do anything with a widget after creating it and adding it to your interface, it's a good idea to keep a reference.

Here is a modification of your code that creates a dictionary `button_dict` to store each of your buttons. The keys are tuples `(row,column)`. I added the `button_dict` as an additional input to your `click` function and modified the button binding to include this new input using `lambda`.

```
import tkinter

def click(event,button_dict):
    space = event.widget
    space_label = space['text']
    row = space.grid_info()['row'] #get the row of clicked button
    column = space.grid_info()['column'] #get the column of clicked button

    button = button_dict[(row,column)] # Retrieve our button using the row/col
    print(button['text']) # Print button text for demonstration

board = tkinter.Tk()

button_dict = {} # Store your button references here

for i in range(0,9): #creates the 3x3 grid of buttons

    button = tkinter.Button(text = i) # Changed the text for demonstration

    if i in range(0,3):
        r = 0
    elif i in range(3,6):
        r = 1
    else:
        r = 2

    button.grid(row = r, column = i%3)
    button.bind("<Button-1>",lambda event: click(event,button_dict))

    button_dict[(r,i%3)] = button # Add reference to your button dictionary

board.mainloop()
```

If you were only interested in the button that was pressed, you can simply access the `event.widget` attribute. From your example, it sounds like you want to modify any number of buttons on each event so I think the dictionary will give you more versatility.

Comment: It's an antipattern to use a additonal sequence like `dict`

Comment: Thanks, I had actually never heard that term before. I looked it up and I understand the basic reasoning. I'll work on avoiding it going forward.

Comment: antipatterns aside, I believe this solves my problem, thanks!