# Deleting all Labels from grid square in tkinter without knowing Labels in first place

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout, python-3.10

So i would like something along the lines of what this code looks like it should do but 'grid()' isn't defined:

```
for label in grid(column = 1, row = 2):
    label.forget()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> w.grid_slaves(row=None, column=None)
>
> Returns a list of the widgets managed by widget w.
>
> If no arguments are provided, you will get a list of all the managed widgets. Use the row= argument to select only the widgets in one row, or the column= argument to select only the widgets in one column.

Refer [finding widgets on a grid (tkinter module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369560/finding-widgets-on-a-grid-tkinter-module/51603425)

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

# Show grid_slaves() in action
def printOnClick(r, c):
    widget = root.grid_slaves(row=r, column=c)[0]
    print(widget, widget['text'])

# Make some array of buttons
for r in range(5):
    for c in range(5):
        btn = tk.Button(root, text='{} {}'.format(r, c),
                        command=lambda r=r, c=c: printOnClick(r, c))
        btn.grid(row=r, column=c)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thats nice. Also, if you want to get all children of an object, you can use `root.winfo_children()`, modify the properties with `.config(text='test')`, get the type of the widget etc. But for this example grid_slaves() does what is asked :)

Answer (score 2):

Even though a proper example was given already, i want to give another example with `winfo_children()` if you want to iterate over all elements without specifying the exact row/column:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button


def my_func():
    # get all children of root
    my_children = root.winfo_children()

    # iterate over children
    for wdg in my_children:
        # print widget information
        print(f"Widget: {type(wdg)},"
              f" Row: {wdg.grid_info()['row']}, Column: {wdg.grid_info()['column']},"
              f" Text: {wdg['text']}")
        # modify text of all labels
        if isinstance(wdg, Label):
            wdg.config(text=wdg["text"] + ".")


root = Tk()
Button(root, text="Click", command=my_func).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

for i in range(1, 4):
    for j in range(3):
        Label(root, text=f"Row {i} Col {j}").grid(row=i, column=j)

root.mainloop()
```